# Teaching OCR to understand NSA and FISC redactions

Tags: unicode, imagemagick, ocr, tesseract, leptonica

I'm maintaining an archive of the heavily redacted documents coming out of the Foreign Intelligence Surveillance Court.

They come with big sections of text that look like this:

[image: screenshot of redacted text]

And when the OCR tries to work with this, you get text like:

> production of this data on a daily basis for a period of 90 days. The sole purpose of this
>
> production is to obtain foreign intelligence information in support of
>
> individual authorized investigations to protect against international terrorism and

So in the OCRed version, where there are blacked out spots, there are just missing words. Sometimes, the missing words create a grammatically correct sentence with a different/weird meaning (like above). Other times, the resulting sentences make no sense, but either way it's a problem. It would be much better if the OCR engine could return X's for these spots or Unicode squares like ▮▮▮▮ instead.

The result I'd like is something like:

> production of this data on a daily basis for a period of 90 days. The sole purpose of this
>
> production is to obtain foreign intelligence information in support of XXXXXXXXXXX
>
> individual authorized investigations to protect against international terrorism and

My question is how to go about getting these X's. Is there a way to analyze the images to identify the black spots? Is there a way to replace them with X's or some better unicode character? I'm open to any ideas to make this look right, but image editing is not a strong suit for me nor is hacking deep within the OCR engine.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to train Tesseract for those long blobs. Depending on the length of the blob, you would assign a different number of 'X' characters. Read [TrainingTesseract3](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/TrainingTesseract3) for training process.